# How can I get combined code coverage from an Azure DevOps Publish Test Results task?

Tags: azure-devops

My Azure DevOps build pipeline has multiple unit test projects.  This prevents me from simply using the "Publish test results and code coverage" option on my .NET Core test tasks, because each one would overwrite the previous result.  This has led me to use a "Publish Test Results" task with the "Merge test results" option to combine all of my test results.  This is working to collect the xunit test results, but I am not seeing any code coverage numbers in my build.  The documentation of the "Publish Test Results" task states..

> You can also use this task in a build pipeline to publish code
> coverage results produced when running tests to Azure Pipelines or TFS
> in order to obtain coverage reporting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=trx%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml

Are there any particular settings I might be missing to get "Publish Test Results" to publish the combined code coverage numbers for all of my projects?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to run the dotnet test command, specify the test results logger and coverage options.

```
--collect "Code coverage"
```

Then use the Publish Test Results task.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testRunner: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
```

For more information, you could refer to [collect code coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#collect-code-coverage).

Comment: I already have "--collect "Code coverage"" in my dotnet test config.  I have "**\\TestResults\\TestResults.xml" in my publish test task, instead of "**/*.trx", because I use xunit.  I can see the .coverage files getting created in my build output, and even though the DevOps build results page completely has the test results, it does not include the code coverage.

Comment: Please check if your problem is related to: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6624

Comment: no, I have confirmed that the .coverage file is created.  It just isn't getting published.

Comment: Have you tried the format: testResultsFiles: ' **/*.xml' ?

Comment: When I was using "**\\TestResults\\TestResults.xml", the test results were getting acknowledged by the Azure DevOps build results, but not the code coverage.